# Can I access my application running on localhost:8080 from WAN..?

Tags: java, tomcat, nat, portforwarding

I developed an application in my home machine. Now I want to show application that i made to client through WAN. I have TP-Link WiFi router at my home. Is it possible using port forwarding or other solution ?

Comment: Yes you can use port forwarding to expose the application to WAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use port forwarding to make your application accessible from the Internet. Essentially, what you want to do is redirect traffic coming into your public IP on port 80 to the internal machine running tomcat on port 8080.

There are [public guides](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/TP-Link/default.htm) available for configuring port forwarding on different routers.

Edit: Port forwarding however might not be the only problem. There are other things to consider:
1. You should use a static external IP and map it to a DNS name, so users will be able to access the site by typing the name in the address bar.
2. You should make sure that the machine running tomcat allows external connections to port 8080, so these aren't blocked by the firewall.

Comment: Hello Matt I forwarded port 8080 but i cant access it from WAN. I don't have static IP to my router at home, my router IP does not show unique when i google "what is my ip" so how to do it...?

Comment: @Sumit You can use a dynamic dns service such as http://www.noip.com/free, https://www.dnsdynamic.org/ or similar services. It'll update the dns record with your IP as it changes.